# What's the meaning of 'compensation is thrown for an activity' and 'compensation is thrown for the current scope'?

Tags: bpmn, flowable

Even if i have read the [compensation-intermediate-throwing-event](https://flowable.com/open-source/docs/bpmn/ch07b-BPMN-Constructs/#compensation-intermediate-throwing-event) of bpmn construct for serveral times, i still cannot understand the meaning of 'compensation is thrown for an activity' and 'compensation is thrown for the current scope'. 
Does it means a compensation-intermediate-throwing-event can be configured to thrown for a specific acivity or can be configured to thrown to current scope?

Comment: Can you please help me to solve my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60925265/6097074

Comment: Sorry, i'm not familiar with flowable-idm as well.